# Connection between entanglement, reversibility, and gravitational waves

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Imagine a movie of the collision between two nuclei, resulting in multiple fragments.  Now imagine the movie running backwards: it looks very implausible.  The laws of physics, being time-symmetric, indicate that the time-reverse process can, nonetheless, actually occur.

HOWEVER, in order to accomplish the reverse collision, it is not sufficient merely to reverse the momenta of all the fragments.  It is also necessary to prepare all the fragments so that they are entangled exactly as they are after the forward collision.  Those entanglements would be crucial to re-forming the two nuclei as a result of colliding all the fragments.

At first glance, the number of degrees of freedom appears to increase in the collision because of the increase in the number of particles. In fact what happens is that entanglements among the fragments produced in the forward collision ensure that the effective number of degrees of freedom after the collision is exactly the same as the number of degrees of freedom before the collision.

My question has two parts: 1) Clearly any electromagnetic waves produced in the forward collision, regardless of their energy, would need to be taken into account in order to engineer the reverse collision, in order to conserve spin.  However, would it also be necessary to account for the infinitesimally small gravitational waves (spin 2) produced in the forward collision? 2) It seems that the probability in a finite universe that two such nuclei would collide is high; but that the probability (in the same universe) that all the fragments would converge with all the right entanglements to run such a collision in reverse is very low.  Given that the laws of physics are time-symmetric, how can the probability be different in forward and reverse scenarios?

Comment: Consider that there are many, many ways in which the collision can proceed, given the inherently non-deterministic nature of the interaction. So, even though each individual post-collision configuration is improbable, their multiplicity balances this out exactly.

Comment: @probably_someone, can you provide some math to back that up?

Comment: Given the effort it would take to entangle a dozen particles in a specific way with respect to spin, momentum, position, excitation states, etc., and simultaneously arrange for photons to arrive at the right time with the right polarization, direction, and frequency to assemble themselves into two nuclei -- compared to the relative ease of colliding two nuclei and seeing what flies out -- a statement that "even though each individual post-collision configuration is improbable, their multiplicity balances this out exactly" needs some backup.

Comment: Causing the collision requires little more than two particle accelerators, because the only necessary correlation between the states of the nuclei is that they need to be very close to each other at some moment, moving at high relative speed.  The reverse collision is vastly more difficult to engineer because simply shooting all the fragments toward the same point, to arrive at the same time, does not provide the necessary entanglement.

Comment: Maybe what I wrote last is not quite correct.  I know it is possible to get photons from two different lasers to interfere, by phase-locking the two lasers.  As I understand it, this would mean that the photons from the two separate lasers are entangled.  The entanglement, however, would result from a vastly different set of causes than the sort of entanglement that results from particle collisions or decays.

Comment: "*I know it is possible to get photons from two different lasers to interfere, by phase-locking the two lasers. As I understand it, this would mean that the photons from the two separate lasers are entangled.*" - If this were true, it would be impossible for such lasers to produce a single photon at a time. I have no idea of any experimental confirmation of my objection, I just believe that a more plausible interpretation is that each photon produced by such lasers is emitted by both lasers simultaneously (similarly to how a single photon passes through both slits in a double-slit experiment.

Comment: Gravitational waves of quantum particles are a subject of quantum gravity. The reason we don't have it is because gravity is not quantum. Quantum gravity makes no sense. To unite QM and GR we need to make QM "classical" again. For example, a photon passes through both slits at the same time as a wave, not just a wave of probability, but a wave of energy, because energy does pass through the slits. This wave is unobservable, but clearly it exists. So QM is fundamentally "classical" while its quantum nature is an artifact of measurement. There are no gravitons. Gravity acts at a deeper level.

Comment: "*the effective number of degrees of freedom after the collision is exactly the same as the number of degrees of freedom before the collision*" - I am not sure what you mean by "degrees of freedom", but doesn't entropy increase in the collision? Surely we have more information after than before. If this is correct, then here you have the entropy arrow of time (despite of logical problems with this concept). The T symmetry is broken by the fact that the worldliness of the proper time for the outgoing particles are not collinear (in other words, by P, and even PT is broken by C - no antimatter).

Comment: As I understand it, from the wavefunction-only perspective (which equates to the Many Worlds perspective) information is never lost and never gained.   What I mean by "number of degrees of freedom" in this context is really the number of parameters required to completely describe the system.